# How to add ID to Wordpress plugin title?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using the [Shapely](https://colorlib.com/wp/themes/shapely/) theme to build a website, and this particular theme uses widgets to create the home page layout and content.

The site I'm working on is currently hosted [here](http://www.maxzara2.geoffaweber.com).

What I am trying to accomplish is adding an ID to the main title (BimFlooring) so I style it individually with CSS. I can modify it without issue, but down the page, there are elements with the same selector (.image-bg p).

How can I add an ID to just the title on the 1st widget so that the other titles further down are not affected?

*Edit: I should mention I have looked through the themes PHP files and for the widget itself and have not come across a place to modify what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use it below selector for only first section css.

## example

/* Below selector for p tag text */

## shapely_home_parallax-1 .image-bg p  { }

/* Below selector for h1 tag text */

## shapely_home_parallax-1 .image-bg h1  { }

Comment: use # sign above the ID like =   #shapely_home_parallax-1

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you so much. I felt like it would be something straightforward like that, but I couldn't find the information anywhere.

Comment: It's my pleasure Geoff. If you need any help in css or wordpress related or any work you can contact me.